# Can all polygons outside of the largest inscribed rectangle in a convex polygon be concave

Tags: geometry

Let $C$ be a convex polygon and $R$ the largest (by area) rectangle lying within $C$. Does there exist a convex polygon $C$ such that when $R$ is removed, all remaining polygons are concave? In other words: Does there exist a polygon $C$ such that all parts of $C \setminus R$ are concave?

**Edit:** I am quite sure the answer is yes, and I think [this site](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/) gives some examples, but not a formal proof.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an example of the existence of such a polygon. Let me know if it fails in some way if I am still misunderstanding your question. Here is $C$:

[image: A quadrilateral that is almost a rectangle]

And in red is our largest rectangle by area, $R$, which I have not proven, but is rather clear I hope. And what is left over in blue is concave.

[image]

Comment: @Blue You were right, of course. My mistake.  Here is a corrected version.

Comment: This is also a counter-example I have been looking at. I think it might be possible to give a proof of the maximality of the rectangle by somehow deriving the area as a function of the rectangles rotation.

Comment: @utdiscant I made the bottom left corner farther out than I would have liked honestly. But I thought staying on the grid lines was better.  If you start with a rectangle and just push one corner a very little bit away from the center, I think you can say that your original rectangle is still the largest.  Obviously that isn't rigorous, but it is my intuition behind the thing.

Comment: Use the applet in the end of this page: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/ to see that this rectangle is maximal.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no (I believe).

This answer is incomplete

---

Suppose there is such a shape $C$.

Consider the largest rectangle $R$ in $C$. If 2 consecutive vertices of $R$ touch $C$, then the part that is cut out will be convex. Hence, in order to fulfill your conditions, at least 1 of any 2 adjacent vertices must not lie on the boundary of $C$. This implies that 2 opposite vertices of $R$ do not lie on the boundary of $C$.

If 4 vertices of $R$ do not lie on the boundary of $C$, it is easy to see that a small expansion will result in a larger $R'$, contradicting the maximality of $R$.

If 3 vertices of $R$ do not lie on the boundary of $C$, notice that due to convexity of $C$, the boundary of $C$ can only touch the perimeter of $R$ at that one vertex. Then, once again, a small expansion from that vertex will result in a larger $R'$, contradicting the maximality of $R$.

Hence, we must have 2 opposite vertices of $R$ (labelled $a, c$) which do not lie no the boundary of $C$, and the other 2 (labeled $b, d$) will lie on the boundary of $C$.

If the boundary of $C$ touches $ba$ or $da$ at a point that is not $b$ or $d$, then the convexity of $C$ implies that the boundary of $C$ touches $a$, which is a contradiction. As such, the boundary of $C$ only touches $R$ at the points $b$ and $d$.

Let $O$ be the center of $R$ (intersection of diagonals). Consider the circle with center $O$ and diameter $bd$. If $ac$ is not the perpendicular (diameter) to $bd$, then by rotating points $a,c$ with respect to $O$, we can find a rectangle $bedf$ inscribed in $O$ with a larger area.

This leaves us with $abcd$ being a square. WLOG, let's use a coordinate system with $O=(0,0), b = (-1, 0), a = (0,1), d = (1, 0), c = (0, -1)$.

Since $a$ and $c$ do not touch the boundary of $C$, let $ 2 \epsilon$ be the minimum of the distance between either of points $a$ or $c$ with the boundary of $C$. Furthermore, set $ \epsilon < 0.1$. Let $ a' = (0, 1+ \epsilon)$, $c' = (0, -1 - \epsilon)$, neither of which points touch the boundary of $C$. By the convexity of $C$, the quadrilateral $a'bc'd$ only touches $C$ at $b$ and $d$.

I feel that we should be able to find a rectangle of area > 2 here, but am unable to do so easily.

Comment: Any rotation of $R$ would result in an *equal-area* $R^\prime$, which doesn't really contradict anything. :) Also: How do you know that the sides of the polygon don't block such a rotation?

Comment: @Blue Sorry, let me clarify why I used the circle $O$ (and there is a loophole here). The sides don't block, because the perimeter doesn't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$C$ is the hexagon with vertices $(0,\pm 1)$, $\bigl(\pm(1+\epsilon),\>\pm\epsilon\bigr)$, where $\epsilon\ll1$. I conjecture that the largest rectangle inscribed in $C$ is the square with vertices $(\pm 1,0)$, $(0,\pm1)$.